# Is there a way to list all Intents and all processes associated with them?

Tags: launcher, task-management, multitasking, processes

Is there a way to list all Intents and all processes associated with them?

Specifics: Droid X, 2.2 stock ROM, rooted.

I'm perfectly fine with any approach, as long as it gets a guaranteed **complete** list:

- A script or a series of commands in Terminal Emulator is fine. No limitation on supposed required technical proficiency (assume that the reader is a qualified long-term Unix power user). As noted, the phone is rooted.
- An app is OK (ideally, it should be able to export the list, but even Autostarts-like GUI display is OK)

  Caveat: if you recommend an app (e.g. [Autostarts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts)), I would request some assurance that it does, indeed, list **all** registered Intent receivers, not merely some sub-set - either as documentation/statement from the author or some other evidence (e.g. analysis of which APIs the code uses).
- Worst case scenario, I'll take an API specifics

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not all, but you can get a pretty good idea [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32707859/1147688):

```
dumpsys activity broadcasts |grep -iE ".+\.[0-9A-Z_\-]+:$" |sort
```

The *grep* expression makes sure to only catch lines ending in the intent like format of `...blahblah.SOME_INTENT:`. I then use *sort* to get it more readable. It may not catch all, but it's a good start.

```
    SIDESYNC.action.CTRL_PRESSED_STATE_EVENT:
    SIDESYNC.action.EXIST_TEXT_BEFORE_CURSOR_STATE_EVENT:
    SIDESYNC.action.INPUT_TEXT_EVENT:
    SIDESYNC.action.PREDICTIVE_TEXT_EVENT:
    SIDESYNC.action.SHIFT_PRESSED_STATE_EVENT:
    SamsungIME.UpdateAvailableLanguageAction:
    android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED:
    android.app.action.DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER_PASSWORD_CHANGED:
    android.app.action.DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.app.action.ENTER_CAR_MODE:
    android.app.action.ENTER_DESK_MODE:
    android.app.action.EXIT_CAR_MODE:
    android.app.action.EXIT_DESK_MODE:
    android.app.backup.intent.INIT:
    android.app.backup.intent.RUN:
    android.app.enterprise.action.ACTION_WIFI_POLICY_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_INVALID_HOST_CALLBACKS:
    android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
    android.bluetooth.adapter.action.LOCAL_NAME_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_IN_RANGE_ALERT:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_OUT_OF_RANGE_ALERT:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.ALIAS_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.AUTO_LOCK_SERVICE:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.device.action.RSSI:
    android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.bluetooth.input.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.content.syncmanager.SYNC_ALARM:
    android.dirEncryption.DirEncryptionManager.UNMOUNT_POLICY:
    android.hardware.display.action.WIFI_DISPLAY_STATUS_CHANGED:
    android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED:
    android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED:
    android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE:
    android.intent.action.ACTIONMEMOFILEPATHFORLOG:
    android.intent.action.ACTION_CLOSE_DIALOG_DATA_ROAMING_GUARD:
    android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED:
    android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED:
    android.intent.action.ACTION_SHOW_DIALOG_DATA_ROAMING_GUARD:
    android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN:
    android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE:
    android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE:
    android.intent.action.AT_CMSS_COMPLETE:
    android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE:
    android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW:
    android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY:
    android.intent.action.BCS_REQUEST:
    android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED:
    android.intent.action.CHAMELEON_PRECONFIG:
    android.intent.action.CHECK_COOLDOWN_LEVEL:
    android.intent.action.CHECK_SIOP_LEVEL:
    android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS:
    android.intent.action.COEX_INFO:
    android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.CSC_CHAMELEON_UPDATE_CALL_SETTINGS:
    android.intent.action.CSC_UPDATE_NETWORK_DONE:
    android.intent.action.CSC_WIFI_DEFAULTAP_DONE:
    android.intent.action.CSC_WIFI_GENERALINFO_DONE:
    android.intent.action.CUSTOMER_TEST_RESPONSE:
    android.intent.action.DATA_CONNECTION_CONNECTED_TO_PROVISIONING_APN:
    android.intent.action.DATA_CONNECTION_FAILED:
    android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.DB_CLEAN:
    android.intent.action.DEFAULT_CS_SIM_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_FULL:
    android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW:
    android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_NOT_FULL:
    android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK:
    android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT:
    android.intent.action.DORMANT_MODE_OFF:
    android.intent.action.DORMANT_MODE_ON:
    android.intent.action.DORMANT_MODE_UPDATE:
    android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE:
    android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED:
    android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED:
    android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED:
    android.intent.action.EMERGENCY_CALLBACK_MODE_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.EMERGENCY_START_SERVICE_BY_ORDER:
    android.intent.action.EMERGENCY_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE:
    android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE:
    android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_CAR_CONNECTED:
    android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_CAR_DISCONNECTED:
    android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_USB_HEADSET_PLUG:
    android.intent.action.FLATMOTION_CP:
    android.intent.action.GCF_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW:
    android.intent.action.GCF_DEVICE_STORAGE_OK:
    android.intent.action.GRIPSENSOR_CP:
    android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED:
    android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG:
    android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.LTE_SMS_STATUS:
    android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION:
    android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON:
    android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED:
    android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED:
    android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIME:
    android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIMEZONE:
    android.intent.action.NOT_ALLOWED_SCREEN_MIRRORING:
    android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED:
    android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED:
    android.intent.action.PALM_DOWN:
    android.intent.action.PDP_RESET_TEST:
    android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE:
    android.intent.action.PROXIMITY_CP:
    android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE:
    android.intent.action.RADIO_TECHNOLOGY:
    android.intent.action.REBOOT:
    android.intent.action.REQUEST_HOME_COUNT:
    android.intent.action.REQUEST_WIDGET_COUNT:
    android.intent.action.SARDEVICE_CP:
    android.intent.action.SB_HIDE_DIALOG:
    android.intent.action.SB_SHOW_DIALOG:
    android.intent.action.SCREENRECORDER_INFORMATION:
    android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF:
    android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON:
    android.intent.action.SECURE_PLAYBACK_START:
    android.intent.action.SECURE_PLAYBACK_STOP:
    android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE:
    android.intent.action.SETTINGS_SOFT_RESET:
    android.intent.action.SET_WIFI:
    android.intent.action.SHOW_BRIGHTNESS_DIALOG:
    android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.SIOP_LEVEL_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.START_FACTORY_TEST:
    android.intent.action.START_NETWORK_BOOSTER:
    android.intent.action.STOP_FACTORY_TEST:
    android.intent.action.STOP_NETWORK_BOOSTER:
    android.intent.action.SWEEP_DOWN:
    android.intent.action.SWEEP_LEFT:
    android.intent.action.SWEEP_RIGHT:
    android.intent.action.SYNC_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.TIME_SET:
    android.intent.action.TIME_TICK:
    android.intent.action.TURNOVERMOTION_CP:
    android.intent.action.UID_REMOVED:
    android.intent.action.USBHID_KEYBOARD_EVENT:
    android.intent.action.USBHID_MOUSE_EVENT:
    android.intent.action.USB_AUDIO_ACCESSORY_PLUG:
    android.intent.action.USB_AUDIO_DEVICE_PLUG:
    android.intent.action.USB_CHARGING:
    android.intent.action.USER_ADDED:
    android.intent.action.USER_BACKGROUND:
    android.intent.action.USER_FOREGROUND:
    android.intent.action.USER_INFO_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT:
    android.intent.action.USER_REMOVED:
    android.intent.action.USER_STARTED:
    android.intent.action.USER_STARTING:
    android.intent.action.USER_STOPPED:
    android.intent.action.USER_STOPPING:
    android.intent.action.USER_SWITCHED:
    android.intent.action.VIDEO_PLAYBACK_STOP:
    android.intent.action.WAITING_AUTO_LOGIN:
    android.intent.action.WB_AMR:
    android.intent.action.WIFIDISPLAY_NOTI_CONNECTION_MODE:
    android.intent.action.WIFI_DISPLAY:
    android.intent.action.WIFI_DISPLAY_SINK_STATE:
    android.intent.action.WIFI_DISPLAY_URL_FROM_NATIVE:
    android.intent.action.proximity_sensor:
    android.intent.action.sec.LSO_CONFIG_CHANGED:
    android.intent.action.sec.MDM_ACCOUNT_DELETE_RESULT:
    android.intent.action.sec.MDM_ACCOUNT_SETUP_RESULT:
    android.intent.action.stk.check_screen_idle:
    android.intent.action.stk.idle_screen:
    android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE:
    android.location.GPS_FIX_CHANGE:
    android.location.MODE_CHANGED:
    android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED:
    android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED:
    android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION:
    android.mtp.MtpClient.action.USB_PERMISSION:
    android.net.ConnectivityService.action.PKT_CNT_SAMPLE_INTERVAL_ELAPSED:
    android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED:
    android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE:
    android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_IMMEDIATE:
    android.net.conn.INET_CONDITION_ACTION:
    android.net.conn.MOBILE_DATA_ENABLE_POPUP:
    android.net.conn.TETHER_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.net.proxy.PAC_REFRESH:
    android.net.wifi.CONFIGURED_NETWORKS_CHANGE:
    android.net.wifi.ERROR:
    android.net.wifi.LINK_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.MAXAP_NOTI:
    android.net.wifi.NETWORK_OXYGEN_STATE_CHANGE:
    android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS:
    android.net.wifi.SEC_NOTIFICATION_CANCEL:
    android.net.wifi.SET_HOME_AP:
    android.net.wifi.SHOW_INFO_MESSAGE:
    android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE:
    android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STA_STATUS_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_WPS_STATE_ACTION:
    android.net.wifi.WIFI_DIALOG_CANCEL_ACTION:
    android.net.wifi.WIFI_OXYGEN_STATE_CHANGE:
    android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE:
    android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.p2p.REQUEST_STATE_CHANGE:
    android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.p2p.STOPFIND_TIMER_EXPIRED:
    android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED:
    android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE:
    android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE:
    android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED:
    android.provider.Telephony.SPN_STRINGS_UPDATED:
    android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED:
    android.security.STORAGE_CHANGED:
    android.server.display.wfd.DISCONNECT:
    android.settings.ALL_SOUND_MUTE:
    android.settings.MONO_AUDIO_CHANGED:
    android.settings.POWERSAVING_AUTO_ENABLE:
    android.settings.POWERSAVING_CHANGED:
    android.settings.POWERSAVING_SWITCH_CHANGED:
    android.settings.PRAYMODE_PREFERENCE_CHANGED:
    android.systemui.usb.STORAGE_NOTIFICATION_CANCEL:
    android.view.volumepanel.CLICK_BUTTON1:
    android.view.volumepanel.CLICK_BUTTON2:
    application/vnd.omaloc-supl-init:
    com.android.action.SIM_REFRESH_INIT:
    com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT:
    com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE:
    com.android.internal.location.ALARM_TIMEOUT:
    com.android.internal.location.ALARM_WAKEUP:
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.Keyguard.PCW_LOCKED:
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.Keyguard.PCW_UNLOCKED:
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.DELAYED_KEYGUARD:
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.sec.UserActivityByShortcut:
    com.android.internal.telephony.cdma.intent.action.TTY_ENABLED_CHANGE:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.bip:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.cbs:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.default:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.dun:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.ent1:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.ent2:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.fota:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.hipri:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.ia:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.ims:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.mms:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-reconnect.supl:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.bip:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.cbs:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.default:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.dun:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.ent1:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.ent2:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.fota:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.hipri:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.ia:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.ims:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.mms:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-restart-trysetup.supl:
    com.android.internal.telephony.data-stall:
    com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DataConnection.DC-1.action_retry:
    com.android.internal.telephony.dcn_result:
    com.android.internal.telephony.provisioning_apn_alarm:
    com.android.keyguard.action.flight_mode:
    com.android.launcher.action.ACTION_HOME_RESTORE:
    com.android.launcher.action.EASY_MODE_CHANGE:
    com.android.mms.LANGUAGE_ACTION:
    com.android.mms.NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION:
    com.android.mms.NOTIFICATION_DELETED_ACTION:
    com.android.nfc.action.INTERNAL_TARGET_DESELECTED:
    com.android.phone.NATURAL_SOUND:
    com.android.phone.NOISE_REDUCTION:
    com.android.phone.action.ACTION_DATA_NOTIFICATION:
    com.android.phone.action.DISABLE_UCE_TOGGLE:
    com.android.phone.sendToCPACPlugged:
    com.android.server.ACTION_EXPIRED_PASSWORD_NOTIFICATION:
    com.android.server.BatteryService.action.DORMANT_END:
    com.android.server.BatteryService.action.DORMANT_START:
    com.android.server.IdleMaintenanceService.action.FORCE_IDLE_MAINTENANCE:
    com.android.server.IdleMaintenanceService.action.UPDATE_IDLE_MAINTENANCE_STATE:
    com.android.server.LightsService.action.UPDATE_SVC_LED:
    com.android.server.MY_INTENT:
    com.android.server.NetworkTimeUpdateService.action.POLL:
    com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.PickupMotionArrived:
    com.android.server.PowerManagerService.action.AUTO_POWER_OFF:
    com.android.server.PowerManagerService.action.FAILED_TO_DETECT_FACE_BEFORE_DIM:
    com.android.server.WifiManager.action.DELAYED_DRIVER_STOP:
    com.android.server.WifiManager.action.DEVICE_IDLE:
    com.android.server.WifiManager.action.REFRESH_BATCHED_SCAN:
    com.android.server.WifiManager.action.START_SCAN:
    com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_POLL:
    com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_UPDATED:
    com.android.server.action.UPDATE_TWILIGHT_STATE:
    com.android.server.am.BROADCAST_DHA_DEBUG_ON:
    com.android.server.am.BROADCAST_DO_TRIM:
    com.android.server.am.BROADCAST_SET_TRIM_TH:
    com.android.server.connectivityservice.CONNECTED_TO_PROVISIONING_NETWORK_ACTION:
    com.android.server.enterprise.ICCID_AVAILABLE:
    com.android.server.enterprise.WFD_DISABLE:
    com.android.server.enterprise.billing.action_enable_status_modified:
    com.android.server.enterprise.billing.mapping_modified:
    com.android.server.enterprise.billing.notification_dismissed:
    com.android.server.enterprise.billing.profile_turn_on_status_modified:
    com.android.server.enterprise.billing.roaming_modified:
    com.android.server.enterprise.billing.wifi_fallback_modified:
    com.android.server.enterprise.kioskmode.REFRESH_HWKEY_CACHE:
    com.android.server.enterprise.restriction.SEND_BLOCKED_MMS:
    com.android.server.enterprise.restriction.SEND_BLOCKED_SMS:
    com.android.server.net.action.ALLOW_BACKGROUND:
    com.android.server.net.action.SNOOZE_WARNING:
    com.android.settings.DEVICE_NAME_CHANGED:
    com.android.settings.LaunchGlanceView:
    com.android.sms.action.CLEAR_ALL:
    com.android.sms.action.SWEEP_NOTIFICATION:
    com.android.sync.SYNC_CONN_STATUS_CHANGED:
    com.android.systemui.BATTERY_LEVEL_TEST:
    com.android.systemui.demo:
    com.android.systemui.power.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW_COCKTAIL_BUTTON:
    com.android.systemui.power.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW_COCKTAIL_TOUCH:
    com.android.systemui.power.action.ACTION_CLEAR_SHUTDOWN:
    com.android.systemui.power.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN:
    com.android.systemui.power.action.POWER_SHARING:
    com.android.systemui.statusbar.ANIMATING:
    com.android.systemui.statusbar.COLLAPSED:
    com.android.systemui.statusbar.EXPANDED:
    com.estrongs.action.chromecast.control.close:
    com.estrongs.action.chromecast.control.disconnect:
    com.estrongs.action.chromecast.control.next:
    com.estrongs.action.chromecast.control.play:
    com.estrongs.action.chromecast.control.preview:
    com.facebook.abtest.action.CLEAR_CACHE:
    com.facebook.abtest.action.UPDATE_CACHE:
    com.facebook.analytics.service.AnalyticsEventUploader.ACTION_ALARM:
    com.facebook.auth.broadcast.ACTION_CLEAR_CACHE_REQUEST:
    com.facebook.backgroundlocation.settings.BackgroundLocationSettingsHandler.updated_settings:
    com.facebook.common.appstate.peers:
    com.facebook.common.executors.WakingExecutorService.ACTION_ALARM.com.facebook.katana:
    com.facebook.common.hardware.NetworkActivityBroadcastManager.NETWORKING_ACTIVE:
    com.facebook.common.hardware.NetworkActivityBroadcastManager.NETWORKING_INACTIVE:
    com.facebook.intent.action.prod.messages.ACTION_CLEAR_ALL_MESSAGES:
    com.facebook.intent.action.prod.messages.ACTION_CLEAR_MESSAGE:
    com.facebook.intent.action.prod.messages.ACTION_NEW_MESSAGE:
    com.facebook.katana.provider.FbSharedPrefsProvider.CHANGED_ACTION:
    com.facebook.messages.ipc.peers.PROD:
    com.facebook.zero.ACTION_FORCE_ZERO_HEADER_REFRESH:
    com.facebook.zero.ACTION_ZERO_REFRESH_TOKEN:
    com.facebook.zero.ZERO_RATING_CLEAR_SETTINGS:
    com.google.android.gms.flp.EXPIRATION_ALARM:
    com.google.android.gms.gcm.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED:
    com.google.android.gms.gcm.PACKAGE_REPLACED:
    com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.action.PAUSE_HOTWORD:
    com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.action.PAUSE_HOTWORD_FIRST_PARTY:
    com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.action.RESUME_HOTWORD:
    com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.action.RESUME_HOTWORD_FIRST_PARTY:
    com.google.android.intent.action.GCM_RECONNECT:
    com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT:
    com.google.android.intent.action.SEND_IDLE:
    com.google.android.location.intent.action.END_LOCATION_BURST:
    com.google.android.location.internal.server.ACTION_RESTARTED:
    com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_INSISTENT_SYNC:
    com.qcom.location.XtraDownloadRequest:
    com.qualcomm.location.geofence.breach:
    com.qualcomm.location.geofence.checkgeofences:
    com.qualcomm.location.ulp.HYBRID_HIGH_POWER_REQUEST_CHANGE:
    com.samsung.accessory.intent.action.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_ITEM:
    com.samsung.action.HS20_EXPIRY_TIME_FOUND:
    com.samsung.android.app.audio.epinforequest:
    com.samsung.android.app.camera.RVF:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.FINGERPRINT_ADDED:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.FINGERPRINT_LOCK_SET:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.FINGERPRINT_PASSWORD_UPDATED:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.FINGERPRINT_REMOVED:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.FINGERPRINT_RESET:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.PRIVATE_MODE_OFF:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.PRIVATE_MODE_ON:
    com.samsung.android.intent.action.UPDATING_APPWIDGET_COMPLETED:
    com.samsung.android.multiwindow.MINIMIZE_ALL:
    com.samsung.android.sdk.samsunglink.SlinkLaunchUtils.BROADCAST_SAMSUNG_LINK_EXITED:
    com.samsung.android.service.hermes.action.collect:
    com.samsung.axt9info.close:
    com.samsung.check.update.schedule:
    com.samsung.cover.NFC.OPEN:
    com.samsung.cover.OPEN:
    com.samsung.cover.REQUEST_REMOTEVIEWS:
    com.samsung.felica.action.LOCKSTATUS_LOCK:
    com.samsung.felica.action.LOCKSTATUS_UNLOCK:
    com.samsung.intent.action.ICC_CARD_STATE_CHANGED:
    com.samsung.intent.action.SIMDB_UNKNOWN_READY:
    com.samsung.intent.action.setCardDataInit:
    com.samsung.knox.ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION:
    com.samsung.knox.ACTION_NEW_NOTIFICATION:
    com.samsung.knox.clipboard.clipremoved:
    com.samsung.knox.clipboard.clipscleared:
    com.samsung.knox.clipboard.sync:
    com.samsung.knox.fmc_incoming_call:
    com.samsung.location.SERVICE_READY:
    com.samsung.pen.INSERT.USER_SWITCH:
    com.samsung.pen.INSERT:
    com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.ALARM_ALERT:
    com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.ALARM_ALERT_FROM_ALARM:
    com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.ALARM_STARTED_IN_ALERT:
    com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.ALARM_STOP:
    com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.ALARM_STOPPED_IN_ALERT:
    com.samsung.spdsuccess:
    com.samsung.wfd.RESULT_WFD_UPDATE:
    com.samsung.wfd.WFD_SESSION_ESTABLISHED:
    com.samsung.wfd.WFD_SESSION_TERMINATED:
    com.sec.GMS_bundling:
    com.sec.android.FindingLostPhone.CANCEL:
    com.sec.android.FindingLostPhone.SUBSCRIBE:
    com.sec.android.FindingLostPhonePlus.CANCEL:
    com.sec.android.FindingLostPhonePlus.SUBSCRIBE:
    com.sec.android.Keyguard.SIDE_TOUCH_UNLOCK:
    com.sec.android.LTE_CA_PARAMETER:
    com.sec.android.LTE_WIDEBAND_INFO:
    com.sec.android.action.CLEAR_MISSED_EVENT:
    com.sec.android.action.NOTIFY_FOCUS_WINDOWS:
    com.sec.android.action.NOTIFY_MULTIWINDOW_STATUS:
    com.sec.android.action.NOTIFY_SPLIT_WINDOWS:
    com.sec.android.app.GCF_MODE_ACTION:
    com.sec.android.app.camera.ACTION_START_BACK_CAMERA:
    com.sec.android.app.camera.ACTION_START_COVER_CAMERA:
    com.sec.android.app.camera.ACTION_START_FRONT_CAMERA:
    com.sec.android.app.camera.ACTION_STOP_CAMERA:
    com.sec.android.app.camera.ACTION_STOP_COVER_CAMERA:
    com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.timer.TIMER_STARTED_IN_ALERT:
    com.sec.android.app.dictionary.SEARCH:
    com.sec.android.app.launcher.MOVE_TO_PRIVATE:
    com.sec.android.app.mms.CB_CLEAR:
    com.sec.android.app.mms.SMS_CB_DIRECT_DISPLAY_RECEIVED:
    com.sec.android.app.mms.SSMS_STATE_FILE_UPDATE:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.GET_ESE_TYPE:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.NFC_CHECK_ESE:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.NFC_CHECK_SIM:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.NFC_DISCOVERY_DISABLE:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.NFC_DISCOVERY_ENABLE:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.NFC_ON_NO_DISCOVERY:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.NFC_TEST_END:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.NFC_TEST_START:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.PRBS_TEST_OFF:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.PRBS_TEST_ON:
    com.sec.android.app.nfctest.SET_ESE_TYPE:
    com.sec.android.app.ocr.OCR_SIP_TEXT:
    com.sec.android.app.ocr3.OCR_SIP_TEXT:
    com.sec.android.app.ocrlite.OCR_SIP_TEXT:
    com.sec.android.app.secsetupwizard.SETUPWIZARD_COMPLETE:
    com.sec.android.app.tmserver.mirrorlink:
    com.sec.android.contextaware.HEADSET_PLUG:
    com.sec.android.emergencymode.UltraPowerSavingManager.ORDER_ULTRA_POWERSAVING_SERVICE:
    com.sec.android.enterprisenotificationcenter.ENTERPRISE_MODE_CHANGE:
    com.sec.android.inputmethod.ACTION_ALARM_LIVELANGUAGE:
    com.sec.android.inputmethod.RequestImeInfo:
    com.sec.android.inputmethod.language_downloaded:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.BUNDLING_POLICY_UPDATED:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.EMERGENCY_MODE_CHANGED:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.INTERNAL_SPEAKER:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.PAUSE_WATCH:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.POWER_SAVING_MODE_CHANGED:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.QUICK_SHOT:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.REQUEST_BACKUP_LOCKSCREEN:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.REQUEST_RESTORE_LOCKSCREEN:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.SSRM_MDNIE_CHANGED:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.SSRM_REQUEST:
    com.sec.android.intent.action.ULTRA_POWER_SAVING_MODE_CHANGED:
    com.sec.android.phone.CHANGED_CALL_NUMBER:
    com.sec.android.phone.action.DataEnable:
    com.sec.android.quicksetting.REFRESH:
    com.sec.android.sconnect.service.ENABLED:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.action.FINISH_SIDESYNC_APP:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.action.KMS_KEYBOARD:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.action.PSS_KEYBOARD:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.source.SERVICE_DESTROY:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.source.SET_BINDER:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.source.SIDESYNC_CONNECTED:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.source.SIDESYNC_HIDE_SIP:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.source.SIDESYNC_INPUT_KEY:
    com.sec.android.sidesync.source.SIDESYNC_LANGUAGE_ID:
    com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.accuweatherdaemon.action.AUTO_REFRESH:
    com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.accuweatherdaemon.action.CHANE_SETTING:
    com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.accuweatherdaemon.action.CHANGE_WEATHER_DATA:
    com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.accuweatherdaemon.action.WEATHER_DATE_SYNC:
    com.sec.factory.app.factorytest.FTA_OFF:
    com.sec.factory.app.factorytest.FTA_ON:
    ...
* Sticky action android.hardware.usb.action.USB_CABLE_STATE:
* Sticky action android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.CHECK_HMT_LEVEL:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.MAX_BRIGHTNESS_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIMEZONE:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.SIG_STR:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.intent.action.SIOP_LEVEL_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED:
* Sticky action android.media.MASTER_MUTE_CHANGED_ACTION:
* Sticky action android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.media.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE:
* Sticky action android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_IMMEDIATE:
* Sticky action android.net.conn.INET_CONDITION_ACTION:
* Sticky action android.net.conn.TETHER_STATE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE:
* Sticky action android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE:
* Sticky action android.net.wifi.p2p.PERSISTENT_GROUPS_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE:
* Sticky action android.os.UpdateLock.UPDATE_LOCK_CHANGED:
* Sticky action android.provider.Telephony.SPN_STRINGS_UPDATED:
* Sticky action com.samsung.android.providers.context.intent.APP_CREATED:
* Sticky action com.samsung.glove.ENABLE:
* Sticky action com.samsung.pen.INSERT:
* Sticky action com.sec.intent.action.SYSSCOPESTATUS:
```

Comment: Does this dump all registered activity, or only intents that are actually triggered while the command runs?

Comment: I believe all registered one, but really IDK because IDK how to check...

Comment: make sure to run `adb shell` first :)

Answer (score 3):

Autostarts parses the application manifests. That's really the best way.

(There is a seemingly auto-generated `broadcast_actions.txt` file shipped with the Android SDK, but it's not complete, in my experience).

Depending on what is wanted, you need to consider:

- That apps can broadcast custom events, and other apps may listen to those custom events.
- That apps can register themselves to receive events at runtime, as opposed to statically in the manifest. Autostarts will not list those, and I am not aware that such temporary registrations are exposed in any way.
- Autostarts only lists broadcast events. Events can also be sent directly to specific activities of specific applications. Autostarts will not list those, but the information can be found in the manifests.

You can also look at `/data/system/packages.xml` on your phone, which is where the `PackageManager` services caches information about installed packages (so it doesn't have to parse the Manifests). I don't remember if it contains information about intents - I vaguely remember that it might not include any application components that have been disabled, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

According to several [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619479/list-intent-filters-for-installed-packages) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011454/listing-an-applications-activity-and-intent-filters) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094109/android-how-to-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-intent-filters) on Stack Overflow, such a list is not available via APIs.

I'm not sure how apps like [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) produce such lists. I wouldn't rule out iterating through all possible intents via the [`queryIntentActivities()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags)) function, or even parsing each installed app's manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I think `adb shell dumpsys package resolvers receiver` is pretty much what you are looking for.